# How do I get correct metrics data even after server restart?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

Suppose I have metrics data for Counter type metrics and there is a scrapper which run every min.
My app generates following data

Day 1

```
attribute_count_total{attr1="value1",attr2="success",attr3="aaa",attr4="value4"} 2.0
attribute_count_total{attr1="value1",attr2="failed",attr3="aaa",attr4="value4"} 1.0
attribute_count_total{attr1="value1",attr2="success",attr3="bbb",attr4="value4"} 3.0
attribute_count_total{attr1="value1",attr2="failed",attr3="bbb",attr4="value5"} 1.0
```

Day 2

```
attribute_count_total{attr1="value1",attr2="success",attr3="aaa",attr4="value6"} 2.0
attribute_count_total{attr1="value1",attr2="failed",attr3="aaa",attr4="value6"} 1.0
attribute_count_total{attr1="value1",attr2="success",attr3="bbb",attr4="value5"} 3.0
attribute_count_total{attr1="value1",attr2="failed",attr3="bbb",attr4="value5"} 1.0
```

Day 3

```
attribute_count_total{attr1="value1",attr2="success",attr3="aaa",attr4="value4"} 2.0
attribute_count_total{attr1="value1",attr2="failed",attr3="aaa",attr4="value4"} 1.0
attribute_count_total{attr1="value1",attr2="success",attr3="bbb",attr4="value5"} 2.0
```

...
...

There can be many combinations of data.
If we count success and failure it is 14 and 5 respectively
If we do total attribute count, it will sum of all success and failure which is 19

what query should I write in promql (grafana) to achieve this?

what would happen if there is app server restart as metrics will be reset to zero? How I retain the count even after the server restart.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Does this query looks correct?
`sum(attribute_count_total)` for total attribute count.
`sum by(attr2) (attribute_count_total)` - for total number success and failed

Comment: See [How does a Prometheus Counter work?](https://www.robustperception.io/how-does-a-prometheus-counter-work/)

Comment: If you intend to sum values of metrics over days, than no, your queries don't look right.

Comment: Can you detail more what you have, and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Consider attribute_count_total is coming from an request/response  through which I fetched certain parameters (in this case - attr1, attr2, attr4 and attr4) and put it in Counter type metrics.
I would like to display how many request success/failed  along with total number of request in grafana dashboard. What promql should I be using achieve this.
What will happen if server restarts.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of your question:

```
sum(attribute_count_total{attr2="success"})

sum(attribute_count_total{attr2="failed"})

sum(attribute_count_total)
```

And so on you can write your promql.

In case of counter reset, you can use functions like `rate` or `increase` to handle any counter drop.

For example for a 1m period:

```
sum(increase(attribute_count_total{attr2="success"}[1m]))
```

@DazWilkin has provided a good [link](https://www.robustperception.io/how-does-a-prometheus-counter-work/) to explain the solution.

You can watch this youtube [video](https://youtu.be/7uy_yovtyqw?t=184) too.

Comment: If I understand where 19 come from (sum of all data points mentioned in the question), your query doesn't provide that. FWIW, I doubt any query can do that. But at this point OP needs to clear up their understanding of counters and situation at hand before any actual useful answer can be made.